# Error while implementing hero animation in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

So, I'm trying to make a bike details UI in flutter and I can't seem to get my hero animation working. First I made a list of bikes with images which on pressed displays the details.I am trying to add hero animation to the image while navigation to another page but the animation is not working
https://gph.is/g/Z8BQPPz

[image: when pressing the image the screen navigate to another page]

```
     Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 6.0),
                  child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {

                          Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              PageRouteBuilder(
                                  pageBuilder: (context, a, b) =>
                                      DetailsOfNewBikes(value: item)));
                        },
                        child: Hero(
                          tag:'item.bikeimage',
                                                      child: Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                    image: NetworkImage(
                                      item.bikeimage,
                                    ),
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                    colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                                      Colors.black26,
                                      BlendMode.darken,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                ),
                                    ),
                        )))
```

and the next page in the image  I have used hero with same tag

```
                  child: new Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Hero(
                    tag:'widget.value.bikeimage',
                                          child: Container(
                                            child: Padding(

                      child: Image.network('${widget.value.bikeimage}'),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0.0),
                    ),
                                          ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 5,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
```

Comment: using same tag won't solve the problem :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each hero widget requires unique hero tag, so that it can identify which widget you want to animated.

```
 tag:'back',
```

here, you are providing back to every widget because of that you are facing this issue.

**Note:** make sure that in **both the screen one hero tag must be same**, so that when you navigate from first screen to second screen widget can find.

Answer (score 3):

You need the same `tag` for your hero animation.

Try using the same tag for both hero widgets. In the example below, I used the `back` tag.

Try the code below, it works perfectly:

**FIRST SCREEN**

```
    Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                      horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 6.0),
                  child: GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {

                          Navigator.push(
                              context,
                              PageRouteBuilder(
                                  pageBuilder: (context, a, b) =>
                                      DetailsOfNewBikes(value: item)));
                        },
                        child: Hero(
                          tag:'back',
                                                      child: Container(
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                    image: NetworkImage(
                                      item.bikeimage,
                                    ),
                                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                    colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                                      Colors.black26,
                                      BlendMode.darken,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                  color: Colors.grey,
                                ),
                                    ),
                        )))
```

**SECOND SCREEN**

```
   child: new Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Hero(
                    tag:'back',
                                          child: Container(
                                            child: Padding(

                      child: Image.network('${widget.value.bikeimage}'),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0.0),
                    ),
                                          ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    height: 5,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
```

To read more on hero animation, check the link below:

[Hero Animation in Flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/hero-animations)

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

`Hero` `tag` should be a unique string, but shared across both screens.

i believe in your case you would want to have the image id as the tag, and when passing to the next screen pass the same id. `item.bikeimage` or something you know is uniq.

```
child: Hero(
                      tag: item.id,
                      child: Container(
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              image: DecorationImage(
                                image: NetworkImage(
                                  item.bikeimage,
                                ),
                                fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                                  Colors.black26,
                                  BlendMode.darken,
                                ),
                              ),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                              color: Colors.grey,
                            ),
                                ),
                    )))


    child: new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Hero(
                tag: widget.value.id,
                child: Container(
                        child: Padding(
                  child: Image.network('${widget.value.bikeimage}'),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0.0),
                ),
                                      ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 5,
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

Comment: it is owkring actually but its fast
can I increase time?